# Joining 3 x MYSQL Tables together with 2 Different Unique Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three Tables that I am having trouble joining because there is not a unique key in between all three
Computers, Clients & Drives

```
*Table Computers*
ComputerID  ClientID    Name        Domain      UserName    OS
========================================================================
1           1           WS01        ABC        Admin        7
2           1           WS02        ABC        Admin        7
3           1           WS03        ABC        Admin        7
4           2           CH21        CORP       Admin        7
5           2           CH22        CORP       Admin        7
6           3           LT33        WGE        Admin        7


*Table Clients*
ClientID    Client Name 
=======================
1       Company1
2       Company2
3       Company3

*Table Drives*
DriveID  ComputerID Letter Size Free Missing FileSystem
======================================================================
1       1       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
2       1       D       102400      100000      0       NTFS
3       1       E       102400      100000      1       FAT32
4       2       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
5       3       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
6       4       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
7       4       F       102400      100000      0       NTFS
8       4       E       102400      100000      1       FAT32
9       4       D       102400      100000      0       NTFS
10      5       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
11      5       D       102400      100000      0       NTFS
12      6       C       102400      100000      0       NTFS
```

I have the following Query:

```
SELECT cl.Name, comp.Name, dr.`Letter`, dr.`Free`,dr.`Size`,dr.`FileSystem`,            
dr.`Missing`   
FROM clients AS cl
INNER JOIN computers AS comp ON comp.`ClientID` = cl.clientid
LEFT OUTER JOIN drives AS dr ON dr.`ComputerID` = comp.`ComputerID`
```

I expect the following results

```
Expected Result:
ClientName ComputerName Letter Free     Size        Filesystem  Missing
=======================================================================
Company1    WS01        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company1    WS01        D       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company1    WS01        E       100000      102400      NTFS        1
Company1    WS02        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company1    WS03        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company2    CH21        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company2    CH21        F       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company2    CH21        E       100000      102400      NTFS        1
Company2    CH21        D       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company2    CH22        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company2    CH22        D       100000      102400      NTFS        0
Company3    LT33        C       100000      102400      NTFS        0
```

Can somebody please explain why I am missing rows when I run the Query shown above & I don't get the expected result. Can they also provide a way to properly join the 3 Tables together when there is not a unique key in-between all three Tables

Comment: The SQL looks sound, just from looking at it, other than the ' around the column names, but I imagine that is a mySQL thing. What results do you get with your query?, or which rows are missing from your expected output?

Comment: The six computers all have drives. So you don't need the left join for this data and you would expect to see 12 drives listed in your results. I count 12 rows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all seems to work for me:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f5d89/1

It is in sql2014, but I don't think SQL flavours will be getting in the way here.

Which rows do you see missing?

Comment: I made a simple mistake. I was typing the wrong table name in my query instead of the Drives I was using a separate table called internal_drives that had the information I was looking for. I found SQLFiddle very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks solid. The only thing I could think that may be an issue is the order of your JOINS.

There is a good article about Join order here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d223e3f-c040-4eb9-a44e-5556e85a821b/inner-join-after-left-outer-join

Comment: Thank you for that Article it was extremely helpful.

Comment: I hope this fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cl.NAME, comp.NAME, dr.`Letter`, dr.`Free`, dr.`Size`, dr.`FileSystem`, dr.`Missing`
FROM Computers AS comp
INNER JOIN Clients AS cl ON comp.ClientID = cl.ClientID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Drives AS dr ON dr.ComputerID = comp.ComputerID
```

What do you mean by missing rows?